# How do I get my Windows CD from Lenovo extra hard drive partition?

Tags: thinkpad, bootable-media

Back in 2007 when I purchased my Lenovo T61 Thinkpad I was told by the support representative that my cd was actually a partition on my hard drive and that if I wanted the cd, I'd have to burn a cd from that partition.

I've looked everywhere on Lenovos support site, but am unable to find steps that will allow me to burn my windows cd. How do I do burn a bootable windows xp cd from some partition that the support tech said was there.

This is on Windows XP.

Comment: First check utilities that came with laptop. You may have option to burn disk in one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same model.  You need to use the Rescue and Recovery program from [the Lenovo site](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-4M7HWZ), if it's not already on your computer, and then follow the instructions in that program to burn a set of recovery disks.  As I remember, you only get to burn one set.  You are correct that the media is burned from the content of the hidden partition.

If none of that works you can supposedly order the media from Lenovo (see the link above).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will let you create a bootable CD, but the recovery partition should be bootable from the boot selection menu.  The key to get to that varies across models but it should tell you what to press on the ThinkPad splash screen at startup.  Usually it's the "Access Thinkpad" or "Access IBM" or "ThinkVantage" key.